# SonarQube - integrationTest.exec - sonarRunner (Gradle) or "sonar-runner" command - showing 0.0% covereage

Tags: testing, integration, code-coverage, sonarqube, jacoco

I'm successfully generating 2 .exec files by Jacoco within "build/jacoco" folder after running a Gradle based build and integration tests.

Gradle command: 
"gradle clean build integrationTest"

Once done, it generates the following .exec files under build/jacoco folder.

1. test.exec
2. integrationTest.exec

Following is my sonar-project.properties file. When, I run "sonar-runner" from Linux prompt it completes but on SonarQube dashboard for this project, I see Unit test says some 34.5% but integration tests says 0.0%. Both .exec files have valid size. I also did "cat" on the .exec files and piped the output to "strings" command in Linux and saw that integrationTest.exec did hit the Tests functions - I have only 1 .java file.

When I run "gradle clean build integrationTest sonarRunner -Dxxx.xxx=yyy -Dyyy.xx=zzz" i.e. by passing all the sonar variable as mentioned in the sonar-project.properties file using -D option, it works but same result on SonarQube project's dashboard. Project's sonar dashboard has both widgets configured for Unit / Integration Tests and I'm including IT tests for showing Overall coverage. Overall coverage is showing 34.5% (which is Unit test % value). Sonar does see test.exec, integrationTest.exec and also auto generates overall-xxx.exec file as well during this operation.

**NOTE:** I'm no where - while starting tomcat on a separate putty / linux console -OR within Gradle build script, providing any value or setting JAVA Agent for Jacoco. I'm getting integrationTest.exec file and test.exec file already so not sure if JVM needs to be stopped once IT tests are complete running. I don't think I need those as i have valid file size for .exec files.

**My ?:**
- Why sonar is not getting IT coverage on the dashboard even though I'm setting / passing the following variable correctly:

```
sonar.jacoco.itReportPath=build/jacoco/integrationTest.exec
```

-bash-3.2$ **cat sonar-project.properties**

```
# Root project information
sonar.projectKey=com:company:product:ProjectA
sonar.projectName=ProjectA
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
# optional description
sonar.projectDescription=ProjectA Service

#Tells SonarQube that the code coverage tool by unit tests is JaCoCo
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco

#Tells SonarQube to reuse existing reports for unit tests execution and coverage reports
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports

# Some properties that will be inherited by the modules
sonar.sources=src/java,test/java,src/java-test

# Sonar Unit Test Report path
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=build/jacoco/test.exec

# Sonar Integration Test Report Path
sonar.jacoco.itReportPath=build/jacoco/integrationTest.exec

sonar.junit.reportsPath=build/UT/results

# Sonar Binaries
sonar.binaries=build/classes/main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Narrowing down the cause: I think it's due to the .exec file for Integration test. To proove it: I passed UT exex file to both reportsPaths in Sonar variables i.e. the following and SonarQube picked both UT/IT test coverage. This prooves that if .exec file for IT tests is good (which I think it's But I need to double check) then Sonar will pick the .exec file and show a valid coverage % instead of 0.0%. Note: the following is just to proove if Sonar is picking the values or not. itReportPath variable should use the .exe file which is generated by Integration tests by Jacoco.

```
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=build/jacoco/test.exec

# Sonar Integration Test Report Path
#sonar.jacoco.itReportPath=build/jacoco/testintegrationTest.exec
sonar.jacoco.itReportPath=build/jacoco/test.exec
```

OK Found the issue. I was running integrationTest task in Gradle and was NOT attaching the jacocoagent.jar (as per Jacoco documentation) to the target JVM (Tomcat's instance) scope. Once I did that, I removed jacoco { ... } section from integrationTest task in Gradle (build.gradle or GRADLE_HOME/init.d/some.common.gradle file as this attach jacoco agent to the Java JVM in which Gradle is running). Now, once jacocoagent.jar was attached to Tomcat's JVM (as per the line below which I added in Tomcat's startup.sh script and added the variable to the command which starts Tomcat), then I ran Gradle (integrationTest) task for running IT tests.

```
PROJ_EXTRA_JVM_OPTS=-javaagent:tomcat/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=build/jacoco/IT/jacocoIT.exec,append=false
```

Then while Gradle was in progress, tests ran and I got a file (jacocoIT.exec at the given location) with some file size BUT this is not yet the final one. I had to stop the Tomcat session/JVM instance by running Tomcat's stop.sh script. Once Tomcat was stopped, I saw jacocoIT.exec file size increased significantly and this was the valid final jacocoIT.exec file (which I needed for sonarRunner Gradle task OR sonar-runner exectuable to pick and successfully push IT code coverage data to project's sonar dashboard). Once done, I got both UT + IT and it's combined code coverage.

```
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=build/jacoco/UT/jacocoUT.exec
sonar.jacoco.itReportPath=build/jacoco/IT/jacocoIT.exec
```