# Integrating Sonar, Jacoco, Gradle, ScalaTest with Junit, Java

Tags: java, scala, gradle, jacoco, sonarqube

I have very successfully integrated Gradle (1.11), Sonar ( 4.1.1 ), Java, Scala and Jacoco in my build process.  I even managed to get info regarding the number of successful tests ( thanks to Stackoverflow! ). I have one problem though.

I can't seem to get info about coverage per test. It would be very nice to have this info.

```
> 15:11:16.514 INFO - Sensor JaCoCoSensor... 15:11:16.535 INFO -
> Analysing C:\example\gradle-sonar-jacoco-scala\build\jacoco\test.exec
> 15:11:17.887 INFO - No information about coverage per test.
```

A simplified version of the project is at : https://github.com/sebastianharko/gradle-sonar-java-jacoco-scalatest-junit

Cheers !

Comment: Are you sure there is such a feature in Sonar? Can you please show some pointers? I'm also evaluating sonar+maven, but didn't get farther than observing overall code coverage.

Comment: Oh, I found it! Should you not have this problem, I wouldn't even know about this feature :) So, thank you!

Comment: Your github example is for scala code that tests java code.  Have you tested coverage reporting with scala testing scala or java testing java?  I ask because I have gradle building some scala projects and it always shows compilation and testing of scala and java separately.

Answer (score 0):

It Looks like you already have

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
```

in your gradle.build

But i'm not seeing a definition to where it's to get it file from in the gradle.build

```
jacoco {
  destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/test.exec")
}
```

If you plan on doing integration and unit testing it would look similar to the following:

```
task "integtest"(type: Test, dependsOn: integtestClasses) {
testClassesDir = sourceSets.integtest.output.classesDir
classpath = sourceSets.integtest.runtimeClasspath

  jacoco {
      destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/integTest.exec")
  }
}
test {
  jacoco {
    destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/test.exec")
  }
}
```

With the corresponding sonar configuration items

```
 property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "$buildDir/jacoco/test.exec"
 property "sonar.jacoco.itReportPath", "$buildDir/jacoco/integTest.exec"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply but it does not solve my problem : 1 ) I don't have any integration testing at this point, just unit testing; 2) Jacoco is working fine, the code coverage is displayed in the Sonar Web Interface ; The problem is that I don't see "coverage per individual test" .. so If I have a test called test1() and a test called test2() , I would like to see that test1() covers 10% of the code, test2() covers 30% of the code, for example.

Comment: According to the code that I see in github your telling sonar to look at the jacoco file without specifying jacoco where to put the .exec.  Which is where setting the destination file comes into play.

Comment: well sonar somohow does figure out where the jacoco file is : See the original post : "Analysing C:\example\gradle-sonar-jacoco-scala\build\jacoco\test.exec" ; so the jacoco file location does not seem to be the problem but I will double check;

Comment: that's because you have it defined at the bottom with the rest of your sonar config.  property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "$buildDir/jacoco/test.exec"

Answer (score 0):

I've seen another conf parameters from [SonarQube - integrationTest.exec - sonarRunner (Gradle) or "sonar-runner" command - showing 0.0% covereage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395182/sonarqube-integrationtest-exec-sonarrunner-gradle-or-sonar-runner-comman) :

The parameter `sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco` called my attention. Did you try that?

Comment: I will double check but as I said before Sonar does manage to see and process the Jacoco file;

Answer (score -3):

You may also want to use [Coveralls.io](https://coveralls.io/)

It's very cheap: only $4.99/mo. and you would have a deep integration with your pull requests on Github (track when a branch increases or decreases your code coverage) as well as [a very nice UI](https://coveralls.io/info/features) to drill down into your code coverage.

Both [SBT](https://github.com/theon/xsbt-coveralls-plugin) and [Gradle](https://github.com/kt3k/coveralls-gradle-plugin) integrations are available.