# Sonar skips integration tests

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan

I need to analyse code via Sonar using Gradle and I have some strange problem which I cannot handle. I have the following project structure

```
-java
  |-src
    |-main
    |-test
    |-integration-test
```

And Sonar analyse only test directory by default and integration-test directory if I change sonar.test property to /src/integration-test, but I want to analyze this two directories together and I actually dont know how to do it. Below we have my sonarqube task properties from gradle.build file.

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectName", "projectName"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "org.sonarqube:projectName"
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://sonar.doesntmetter"
        property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
        property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "build/test-results/test"
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "build/jacoco/test.exec"
        property "sonar.jacoco.itReportPath", "build/jacoco/integrationTest.exec"
    property "sonar.login", "admin"
    property "sonar.password", "admin"
    }
}
```

What I noticed is that when I run gradle build there would be integrationTest.exec and test.exec in /build/jacoco/ directory, but in case I run gradle sonarqube with default sonar.test property there would be only test.exec, and from other hand when I run gradle sonarqube with sonar.test=/src/integration-test there would be both test.exec and integrationTest.exec.

Dont you know how to analyze unit and integration test in one run?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add this to your Gradle:

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        properties["sonar.sources"] += sourceSets.custom.allSource.srcDirs
        properties["sonar.tests"] += sourceSets.integTest.allSource.srcDirs
    }
}
```

Just use `+=` to add more tests/sources.
More information and examples are [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle).

EDIT:

Add report paths too! Properties are named:

**sonar.surefire.reportsPath** - test.testResultsDir (if the directory exists)

**sonar.junit.reportsPath** - test.testResultsDir (if the directory exists)

EDIT:

I rewrite your code and set sources for testing in one line, check it with your structure

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectName", "projectName"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "projectKey"
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://itsprettyprivate"
        property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
        // Or add it via += to properties, it is up to you ;)
        property "sonar.sources", "src/java,src/test,src/integration-test"
        //Tells SonarQube where the unit tests execution reports are
        property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "build/test-results/test"
        //Tells SonarQube where the unit tests code coverage report is
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "build/jacoco/test.exec"
        //Tells SonarQube where the integration tests code coverage report is
        property "sonar.jacoco.itReportPath", "build/jacoco/integrationTest.exec"
        property "sonar.login", "admin"
        property "sonar.password", "password"
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt help, there i still have only statistics for unit tests

Comment: And you only missing reports but tests were runned? Then you need to add more properties for reportPath: `sonar.surefire.reportsPath`
`sonar.junit.reportsPath`

Comment: actually integration tests dont run

Comment: should I add reportsPath for integration test same as sonar.tests?

Comment: Post you new configuration please :) I will try to look at it and post it

Comment: http://pastebin.com/aAvn4wLx
There is my current configuration. When I run sonarqube locally I dont have integrationTest.exec in jacoco directory, from the other hand when I run sonar on Jenkins there is this file but this doesnt change antyhing. 
Anyway at this moment I would like to express my appreciation to you, thanks for trying help.

Comment: @JoDung I found it already solved :) Check it here, here you are able to see how to set http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395182/sonarqube-integrationtest-exec-sonarrunner-gradle-or-sonar-runner-comman .